# How do I separately convert a struct timeval into two 32 bit variables?

Tags: c, timeval

A struct timeval is 64 bit long. I need, for a project, to convert this long (struct timeval) into two 32 bit chunks, and put each chunk into a different variable. How do I do this?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you use the normal `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` members (see [docs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/sys/time.h.html))?

Answer (score 2):

```
uint32_t* values = &timevalstruct;

// depends on endianess

uint32_t v1 = values[0];
uint32_t v2 = values[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to leppie's answer:

```
union tvs
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct ints {
        uint32_t v1;
        uint32_t v2;
    };
};

tvs t;
t.tv = timevalstruct;
uint32_t v1 = tv.ints.v1;
uint32_t v2 = tv.ints.v2;
```

if you dont want to deal with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

See this :
http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday

Can you use tv_sec and tv_usec fields of the timeval structure?

Comment: yeah, that's what I just decided to do. Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct timeval tv;
...
uint32_t seconds = tv.tv_sec;
uint32_t micros = tv.tv_usec;
```

There you go, separated into 32-bit integers.